# Are .net SqlDataReader methods culture invariant

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, currentculture, invariantculture

I can't really find a definitive answer to what happens if for example my decimals are stored in the database with different culture settings and I want to get them via a SqlDataReader into my program. Will the ',' and '.' always be correctly parsed and converted to my current culture as long as the data type in the SQL-DB is set to decimal?

What happens if they are stored in a varchar and try to use .GetDecimal()?

Comment: `What happens if they are stored in a varchar and try to use .GetDecimal()?` What happened when you tried it?

Comment: "What happens if they are stored in a varchar and try to use .GetDecimal()?" You get a big fat exception saying that your column doesn't have the expected type, that's what. `SqlDataReader` does not perform conversions between any data types. Even (say) reading an `INT` value with `GetInt64` will fail, even though all `INT` values can be represented in an `Int64`.

Comment: Unfortunately, `string` (`varchar`, etc) are *easy types to deal with* because "everything can be treated as a string"; The unfortunate aspect is that they're often the *least appropriate* type to use.

Answer (score 4):

> Are .net SqlDataReader methods culture invariant

`SqlDataReader` does not use any `CultureInfo` or something equivalent. It's not aware of cultures.

When your values are stored in the db as decimal, the SqlDataReader receives that decimal value. How they are (string-) represented in your app then depends how you do it: simply with `dataReader["myColumn"].ToString()` will use your current `CultureInfo`. If you want a different culture, you have to provide that explicitly.

> What happens if they are stored in a varchar and try to use .GetDecimal()?

When they are stored as strings, you have a problem (at least if you don't know the culture these strings were created with). You have to use the correct `CultureInfo` to first *parse* those strings to get the correct values. But why would you store numbers as strings in your db, anyway?